# How to put image in a picture box from Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, image

Is it possible to load a picture from memory (`byte[]` or `stream` or `Bitmap`) without saving it to disk?

This is the code I use to turn the `byte[]` array into a `Bitmap`:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = Misc.ConvertFromUInt32Array(image))
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 64, 800, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(ptr));
        bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
        bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
        bmp.Save("test.bmp");
    }
}
```

Instead of using `Bmp.save()`, can I put the `Bitmap` in the picture box on my form?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
pictureBox.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: This code worked for me. `this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);`

Answer (score 8):

I had some code resembling the accepted answer that caused a memory leak. Problem is that when you set the picture box image to the bitmap, you're still referring to the bitmap, rather than creating a copy. If you need to set the image multiple times you need to make sure you're disposing all the old bitmaps.

This is for anyone who's looking to *clone* a bitmap to an image box. Try this:

```
if (pictureBox.Image != null) pictureBox.Image.Dispose();
pictureBox.Image = myBitmap.Clone(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height), 
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying to use the bitmap without cloning it was throwing an exception in the System.Drawing.Dll. Using your .Clone suggestion fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with C++ programming language, it can be done like this:

```
void backGroundImage()
{
    Image^ back = gcnew Bitmap("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\image.bmp");
    pictureBox1->BackGroundImage = back;
};
```

Then you can call `backGroundImage` when you need to load a bitmap.