# Load Picturebox Image From Memory?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I can't seem to figure out how to load a pictureBox image from a bitmap in memory.  Is it possible or do I have to create temp file for the bitmap?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743549

Comment: How do you have the bitmap in memory?

Comment: It is the opposite, loading the image from a file, that is unusual.  Use the Bitmap class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What format is the image in memory?

If you have an actual Bitmap object, just assign it to the PictureBox, as suggested by dtb:

```
pictureBox.Image = bitmap;
```

If you have the image as a series of bytes held in a stream, you'll need to load the image from the stream:

```
var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
pictureBox.Image = image;
```

If you instead have a windows GDI handle to the bitmap, use

```
var image = Image.FromHbitmap(handle);
pictureBox.Image = image;
```

Essentially, it's hard to answer your question with more than suggestions when you haven't told us what format the Bitmap you have is held in.

Comment: I have received `System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.` exception when i tried to load image from stream.

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu I suggest posting your own question to get assistance with your particular context; it's difficult to assist with so little information.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a Bitmap from a MemoryStream:

```
pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(byteArray));
```

Comment: at what point is it safe to explicitly Dispose of the MemoryStream ? Would : using(var ms = new MemorySteam(byteArray)){ pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(ms) }; be safe ?

Comment: @MoeSisko: You don't really need to dispose a MemoryStream; they don't have unmanaged resoruces.  (just a `byte[]`)  But, yes; that should be fine.

Comment: parameter missing here `Dim picture As Byte() = GetBytes(ListView2.Items(index).SubItems(8).Text)

        Dim converter As New ImageConverter()
        PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(converter.ConvertFrom(picture), Image)`

Answer (score 2):

```
pictureBox.Image = bitmap;
```

Comment: parameter missing here `Dim picture As Byte() = GetBytes(ListView2.Items(index).SubItems(8).Text)

        Dim converter As New ImageConverter()
        PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(converter.ConvertFrom(picture), Image)`