# Parameter is not valid while converting byte array to image

Tags: c#, database, linq, parameters

i have a database with an image filed.I have read this Image field and convert to byte array with code below.

```
imageByte = ((dtgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value) as System.Data.Linq.Binary).ToArray();
```

When I Create a stream and Assign it to PictureBox image like this:

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

I have this error:

> Parameter is not valid.

How Can I fix this.

Comment: Maybe try one of these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576868/how-to-put-image-in-a-picture-box-from-a-byte-in-c-sharp

Comment: This is most likely to be because `imageByte` does not actually contain valid image data.  Have you verified that it is, in fact, a valid image, before loading it into the picture box?

Comment: Martin@You say the right thing.thank u.data was wrong.i fix it